# blank screen on website after configuring apex domain and www subdomain variant on github

Tags: dns, github-pages, svelte, vite

I am using `vite+svelte` wanted to host my webpage using `github pages`

Deployed `Vite app` as showed in the video [How to Deploy Your Vite App to Github Pages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yo2bMGnIKE8)

Create a repo `repo1` on `github`

all stuff

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https:// ........git
```

Changed the base url inside `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: '/repo1/',
  plugins: [svelte()]
})
```

`npm run build`

`git add dist -f`

`git commit -m "add dist"`

`git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

Got website running with this extension `https://name.github.io/repo1/`

Wanted to add a custom domain to the repo1

Saw this page [Configuring an apex domain and the www subdomain variant](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain-and-the-www-subdomain-variant)

First configure an apex domain with `A` record

```
On GitHub, navigate to your site's repository.

Under your repository name, click  Settings.

Repository settings button

click Pages

Under "Custom domain", type your example.com, then click Save

Check for CNAME created inside repo1 containing example.com

Changed A record in DNS provider

185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

Then configured a CNAME record with your DNS provider

type `CNAME` name `www.example.com` data `username.github.io.`

confirmed if DNS record configured correctly using

`dig WWW.EXAMPLE.COM +nostats +nocomments +nocmd`

I had to get this output

```
> ;WWW.EXAMPLE.COM.                     IN      A
    > WWW.EXAMPLE.COM.              3592    IN      CNAME   YOUR-USERNAME.github.io.
    > YOUR-USERNAME.github.io.      43192   IN      CNAME    GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER .
    >  GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER .         22      IN      A       192.0.2.1
```

But what I got is

```
;WWW.EXAMPLE.COM.   IN  A
WWW.EXAMPLE.COM. 9999   IN  CNAME   YOUR-USERNAME.github.io.
YOUR-USERNAME.github.io. 9999 IN    A   185.199.111.153
YOUR-USERNAME.github.io. 9999 IN    A   185.199.109.153
YOUR-USERNAME.github.io. 9999 IN    A   185.199.110.153
YOUR-USERNAME.github.io. 9999 IN    A   185.199.108.153
```

I never got these

`username` pointing to `github-pages-server`

`> YOUR-USERNAME.github.io.      43192   IN      CNAME    GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER .`

`github-pages-server` pointing to `IP`

`>  GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER .         22      IN      A       192.0.2.1`

When I tried checking `www.example.com` my custom domain I get a `blank white screen` no `errors` or  `warning` message on the website just a white screen

I came across this [How to Configure GitHub Pages Custom Domain? (Google Domains | Subdomain & Apex Domain)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5ZtKvk3Sag)

He too gets a `blank white screen` without any kind of `error` or `warning` messages on page load just as mine he `inspects` the page gets 404 error on `console`

When I checked my custom domain `inspect -> console`

Even i got similar warning

```
example.com/:8
GET https://example.com/repo1/assets/index.b0a7898d.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
example.com/:9          
GET https://example.com/repo1/assets/vendor.8c7ac98a.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
example.com/:10          
GET https://example.com/repo1/assets/index.897361a6.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

He adds homepage inside `package.json`

```
  "homepage": "https://example.com",
```

Saves pushes the code on github and website starts working

How do I correct this?

Do I add '"homepage": "https://example.com",' inside `package.json`?

Or

Should I change the `base` URL inside `vite.config.js` from `/repo1/` to `example.com`?

OR

have I missed anything in between?

I am confused please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through `vite` documentation

[base](https://vitejs.dev/config/?#base) is required to be specified inside `vite.config.js`

```
base
    Type: string
    Default: /
    Base public path when served in development or production. Valid values include:
        Absolute URL pathname, e.g. /repo-name/
        Full URL, e.g. https://example.com/
        Empty string or ./ (for embedded deployment)
```

default `vite.config.js` file content below

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()]
})
```

When deploying with `https://user-name.github.io/repo-name/`
add `base` with `repo-name`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default defineConfig({
    base: '/repo-name/',
  plugins: [svelte()]
})
```

When deploying with `https://example.com`(your custom domain)
add base with `https://example.com`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default defineConfig({
    base: 'https://example.com/',
  plugins: [svelte()]
})
```

Then `npm run build` update to your github repo, same procedure

Got my site running